# Auto Insert into MySql Data Base

Tags: php

When one User Enter all his/her details after enter he will get a message like his registration no /ID is Like:
A0001
2nd is 
A0002
like this upto A1000
after this the registration no automaticaly change to B0001

Is It Possible!!!!!

```
for ($i = 'A'; $i != 'AA'; $i++) 
{
$prefix = $i;
$id = $prefix.sprintf("%03s",$suffix);
for ($j=1;$j<=5;$j++) 
{

$res = "$id"."$j";
echo "$res"."<br>";

}
}
```

this is the code only to A005 to Z005 but how can i able to pick A001 and insert into mysql database first column.

Comment: You should at least try to write some code and see what you can come up with, but yes it is possible.

Comment: Can you please narrow this question down? It is too broad and shows zero effort on your part at the moment.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please add the code you already have or what you've tried. Further have a look at the other questions how they have been written to get a better style of your question.

Comment: Mr. chillOr i change the content please check this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite simple:

1st what you want to do is to query the database for the previous registration no /ID.

something like this:

```
$query = mysqli_query($connect,'SELECT regCode From data ORDER BY regCode DESC LIMIT 1');
```

then you check if there is any result like this:

```
$results = count(mysqli_num_rows($query));
```

if it $results returns 0 (it is a fresh database) do this:
`$regCode = 'A0001';`

else:

create an array of alphabets.

`$alphabet = ['B','C','D','E']; #from B to Z (A is omitted because it is the default prefix)`

retrieve previous regCode like this:

```
list($regCode) = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
```

From here seperate the alphabet from the numbers

```
$prefix = substr($regCode,0,1);  //get prefix/alphabet
$storage_id = (int) substr($regCode,1,4) +1; //get code and add 1
```

Now test for the limit which in our case is 1000 (or any number you want):

```
$limit = 1000

if($storage_id>$limit){
    $storage_id= '0001'; //if limit exceeded reset storage id
    $index = array_search($prefix,$alphabet); //get alphabet/prefix index in the $alphabet array

    if($index>=0){
        $prefix = $alphabet[$index+1]; //Get next alphabet
    }
}else{
    //when limit is not exceeded do this
    if(strlen($store)!=4){ //check the length of our regCode (should be 4 letters in this case if not add some zeros)
        $storage_id = str_pad($storage_id,4,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);
    }
}

$regCode = $prefix.$store; //combine alphabet to new storage_id
echo $regCode;
```

And that's it !!!

This is the full code. Just copy this:

```
<?php
mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db('test');

if(isset($_REQUEST['submit']))
{
$query = mysql_query('SELECT regno from details ORDER BY regno DESC LIMIT 1');
$results = mysql_num_rows($query);
if($results==0){
    $regCode = 'A0001';
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO details (regno) VALUES('{$regCode}')");
}else{
    list($regCode) = mysql_fetch_row($query);
    $alphabet = array('B','C','D','E');
    $prefix = substr($regCode,0,1);  //get prefix/alphabet
    $storage_id = (int) substr($regCode,1,4) +1;

    $limit = 1000;

if($storage_id>$limit){
    $storage_id= '0001'; //if limit exceeded reset storage id
    $index = array_search($prefix,$alphabet); //get alphabet/prefix index in the $alphabet array

    if($index>=0){
        $prefix = $alphabet[$index+1]; //Get next alphabet
    }
}else{
    //when limit is not exceeded do this
    if(strlen($storage_id)!=4){ //check the length of our regCode (should be 4 letters in this case if not add some zeros)
        $storage_id = str_pad($storage_id,4,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);
    }
}
$regCode = $prefix.$storage_id; //combine alphabet to new storage_id
mysql_query("INSERT INTO details (regno) VALUES('{$regCode}')");
    }
echo $regCode;
}
?>
<form name="form" id="form" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Mr. Kelvin is it the code which i may need to try??

Comment: @sameerkumar your code won't work because: i was using mysqli_query, you are using mysql_query. when you use mysql_query there is no need for the $connect. then do you have the table details in your database?

Comment: Thank You Mr. @Kelvin Kehinde Omolumo this code is 110% working.